# How do I apply a Shared Advanced Segment to my data using a service account?

Tags: python-3.x, authorization, google-analytics-api, segment

I am using the [Google Analytics Reporting API v4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) with Python3 to extract data from a Google Analytics dashboard that is shared to me by my boss. I am using a private key and a service account.

What I want to do: Use a Custom/Advanced Segment that was created by the Admin of the Google Analytics dashboard. This admin has changed the Advanced Segment to a collaborative segment, so I can access the segment on my account.

**I am able** to extract data for predefined segments like (gaid::-3). But this is only the test case. The problem arises when I try to use a Custom/Advanced Segment instead of a predefined Google segment.

Code:

```
"""Hello Analytics Reporting API V4."""

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
KEY_FILE_LOCATION = 'fakefilelocation.json'
VIEW_ID = '111111'


def initialize_analyticsreporting():
  """Initializes an Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.

  Returns:
    An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
  """
  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
      KEY_FILE_LOCATION, SCOPES)

  # Build the service object.
  analytics = build('analyticsreporting', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

  return analytics


def get_report(analytics):
  """Queries the Analytics Reporting API V4.

  Args:
    analytics: An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
  Returns:
    The Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
  """
  return analytics.reports().batchGet(
      body={
        'reportRequests': [
        {
         "viewId":VIEW_ID,
         "dimensions":[{"name": "ga:segment"},{"name":"ga:dimension4"}],
         "dateRanges":[{"startDate":"2017-10-10","endDate":"2017-10-10"}],
         "metrics":[{"expression":"ga:sessions","alias":"sessions"}],
        "segments":[{"segmentId": "gaid::1111111111111"}]
        }]
      }
  ).execute()


def print_response(response):
  """Parses and prints the Analytics Reporting API V4 response.

  Args:
    response: An Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
  """
  for report in response.get('reports', []):
    columnHeader = report.get('columnHeader', {})
    dimensionHeaders = columnHeader.get('dimensions', [])
    metricHeaders = columnHeader.get('metricHeader', {}).get('metricHeaderEntries', [])

    for row in report.get('data', {}).get('rows', []):
      dimensions = row.get('dimensions', [])
      dateRangeValues = row.get('metrics', [])

      for header, dimension in zip(dimensionHeaders, dimensions):
        print(header + ': ' + dimension)

      for i, values in enumerate(dateRangeValues):
        print('Date range: ' + str(i))
        for metricHeader, value in zip(metricHeaders, values.get('values')):
          print(metricHeader.get('name') + ': ' + value)

def main():
  analytics = initialize_analyticsreporting()
  response = get_report(analytics)
  print_response(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

But this results in an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HttpError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-f6bd25c075a6> in <module>()
     76 
     77 if __name__ == '__main__':
---> 78   main()

<ipython-input-10-f6bd25c075a6> in main()
     72 def main():
     73   analytics = initialize_analyticsreporting()
---> 74   response = get_report(analytics)
     75   print_response(response)
     76 

<ipython-input-10-f6bd25c075a6> in get_report(analytics)
     41          "dateRanges":[{"startDate":"2017-10-10","endDate":"2017-10-10"}],
     42          "metrics":[{"expression":"ga:sessions","alias":"sessions"}],
---> 43         "segments":[{"segmentId": "gaid::1111111111111"}]
     44         }]
     45       }

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\_helpers.py in positional_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    131                 elif positional_parameters_enforcement == POSITIONAL_WARNING:
    132                     logger.warning(message)
--> 133             return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    134         return positional_wrapper
    135 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py in execute(self, http, num_retries)
    840       callback(resp)
    841     if resp.status >= 300:
--> 842       raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
    843     return self.postproc(resp, content)
    844 

HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet?alt=json returned "User does not have sufficient permissions for this advanced segment.">
```

I'm pretty sure that this is not the result of a bad segment ID, because I tried a fake one ("1111111111111") and it gave me a different error.

**To Summarize**
I want to use Google Analytics Reporting API v4 to extract and print data that has been sorted by a Custom/Advanced Segment which is owned by the Admin user, not by me. This way, if the Admin changes the settings on the Custom Segment, the changes will flow through to my data extraction naturally.

Comment: Did yo solve this in the meantime?

Comment: @FabianBosler No I did not. I ended up switching to Excel, using a tool called "Analytics Edge": https://www.analyticsedge.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you change the visibility setting of the segment to "Collaborators and I can apply/edit Segment in this View" the service account should be able to see it.

In the Google Analytics web interface, edit the segment (admin > view > segments > pick the appropriate segment). In the top right, where it says "Segment is visible and shared in current View," click "Change" and apply the new setting.

[image: Screenshot of Google Analytics segment editor]

[Google support link](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6121378?hl=en#availability)